# How-to check if user is logged in asp.net and depending on if they are logged in display a certain page?

Tags: asp.net, authentication

I have a very basic understanding of ASP.NET and I am trying to do the following. I have a home page that is set-up to be a login page. If you could just picture a username and password box that is the extent of that home page. Once the user is logged in they will go to a different page let's say the account page. However, when the user clicks the logo at the top left hand it takes them to the home page again but it shows the username and password boxes again ready to be filled.

The user status at the top of my page still shows that the user is logged in. What I am trying to do is add a piece of code that will change the link of the logo to display the account page once they are logged in and not the login page.

I don't know if this can be done through the web.config file since I read a different article that has something similar to this or if this code can be put directly next to the code where my logo link (default.aspx) sits.

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

Research the [Membership Provider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh26yfzy.aspx).

It's an industry standard in ASP.NET session management.  It will manage all of your pages and allow you to customize pages, menus, etc. based on roles and permissions.  Don't reinvent the wheel if you have the oppertunity to use it.

Straight from MSDN:

> ASP.NET membership supports facilities
>   for:
>
> Creating new users and passwords.
>
> Storing membership information (user
>   names, passwords, and supporting data)
>   in Microsoft SQL Server, Active
>   Directory, or an alternative data
>   store.
>
> Authenticating users who visit your
>   site. You can authenticate users
>   programmatically, or you can use the
>   ASP.NET login controls to create a
>   complete authentication system that
>   requires little or no code.
>
> Managing passwords, which includes
>   creating, changing, and resetting them
>   . Depending on membership options you
>   choose, the membership system can also
>   provide an automated password-reset
>   system that takes a user-supplied
>   question and response.
>
> Exposing a unique identification for
>   authenticated users that you can use
>   in your own applications and that also
>   integrates with the ASP.NET
>   personalization and role-management
>   (authorization) systems.
>
> Specifying a custom membership
>   provider, which allows you to
>   substitute your own code to manage
>   membership and maintain membership
>   data in a custom data store

Comment: I read the link you sent...many thanks..but like I mentioned I know bare minimum ASP.NET I see that I can use "The ASP.NET login controls (Login, LoginView, LoginStatus, LoginName, and PasswordRecovery) which encapsulate virtually all of the logic required to prompt users for credentials and validate the credentials in the membership system." 
But still don't know where to put any of the code to check for this and redirect the page. Sorry...but I appreciate your help.

Comment: @Octavio Following [this link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff184050.aspx) off that MSDN page takes you to a step-by-step walkthough for building a simple page that requires login - that should get you started.

Comment: @djacobson thanks! I think I can do the walk through and apply some of the principals to what I already have. I will post more when I figure out more. I truly appreciate your help.